# To send html in the body of the mail using python

Tags: python, html, email

I want to display the output of the html file in the body of the mail using python, without copying the html code in the python program

Comment: Okay. Read the HTML from a file into a string, then use that string where you'd otherwise have the HTML string in your code.

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/

Jinja2 is commonly used to build HTML with a Python backend web server. It can be used in combination with Flask, Django, Dart, CherryPy etc.